# Standard library for schnorr signature algorithm

Tags: blockchain, signature, python, schnorr-signatures, library

I am trying to create a **blockchain** demonstration to get used to the technology. The thing is: I want to use ***Schnorr signatures***, but I can't seem to find a library for that, and I want to make sure that I don't use anything poorly implemented.

I searched for libraries on GitHub but the ones I could find were not general enough or just not what I need.

Oh, and I am using **Python**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The BIP340 standard that describes Schnorr signatures over the elliptic curve secp256k1 includes a [Python reference implementation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki#test-vectors-and-reference-code). As mentioned it is a naive implementation not meant for production use, so be sure to only use it for demonstration purposes, but it has the advantage of being as correctly implemented as you could hope.

Comment: So bitcoin devs created their own implementation of Schnorr? And, if so, did they use C++?

Comment: @rafael__bg The production-ready implementation of BIP340 Schnorr signatures used by Bitcoin Core is written in C and you can find it in the [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) library.